# How to retrieve multiple item from single call to DB and bind to multiple dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

New to MVC.

In my page I have several drop down. Currently this is my approach and I feel like repeating myself.

I have created a model, so that I can reuse it for all the dropdown.

```
public class NameValueModel
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then I wrote a data class to fetch value for each dropdown

```
    public IEnumerable<NameValueModel> GetStatus()
    {
       return (from m in ne.Status
               select new NameValueModel { Value = m.StatusID, Name = m.Name }).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<NameValueModel> GetStates()
    {
        return (from m in ne.tblStates
                select new NameValueModel { Value = m.StateId, Name = m.Name }).ToList();
    }
```

Like wise same code is repeated for each drop down.

Now in my Controller I am calling each of this public method to populate ViewBag

```
 public ActionResult Index(FormCollection f)
 {
        ViewBag.StateList = new SelectList(new StudentData().GetStates(), "Value", "Name");
        ViewBag.ProgramType = new SelectList(new StudentData().GetStatus(), "Value", "Name");

        // More of the above
        return View();
 }
```

My concern is that I am populating viewBag one by one for each drop down and I have 10 of them, and I am not happy about it.. Is there more sleeker way to get value for all the dropdown as one single call to DB, Cache it, One Model, One call from controller and get all the values for binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `stored procedure` which will return multiple result set and use the `DataSet` to store the result. Each `DropDownList` value will be in a saperate table inside the resultant `DataSet`.